# SAPUI5 - Send email via popup dialog box

Tags: dialog, sapui5

I'm wondering if it is possible to send an email in SAPUI5 via a dialog component. I have a dialog box that opens on button press and the requirement is to send a query (with optional attachment) to a email address (a possible of 5 different addresses depending on the option you select for the Subject select component).

[image: Query form in a dialog component]

Is this possible?

As an alternative option, I have seen the URL helper component which when pressed it loads up a mail client (eg, Outlook) but the business wanted it in a contact form style if possible.

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.UrlHelper/preview

Answer (score 0):

On the alternative option is this what you need?

```
sap.m.URLHelper.triggerEmail("Smith, John <john.smith@sap.com>", "Info Request");
```

Comment: The URL helper would be a last resort. 

What is really needed is if there is a way to send an email using a dialog and pulling the data entered into an input, select and text area component.